# How to enable IP fragmentation in embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp

I have 3.8 linux kernel. I have created /sys/class/net in my device to receive control packets i.e. protocol related packets from other devices. However, sometime these protocol messages are too big to receive. Thus, my device gets fragmented data. However, when I did a packet capture, I could see some Frame check sequence errors. My guess is that some packets were lost due to the fragmented data. My protocol relies on IP layer to handle fragmentation rather than handle by itself.

My question is how do I enable or check IP fragmentation support is enabled or not in the linux kernel? The MTU of my network device is 1500 and I am sending 1590 bytes from other host.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIN, there is no way to disable linux IP fragmentation explicitly, for more information ,you can refer to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt